# Displaying time chart in achartengine based on months and years

Tags: android, achartengine

I have a line graph based on my database values where y axis has values and x axis has dates. As of now the chart is displayed date wise. But i want to display it different time periods like monthly and yearly.

Can anyone give me any ideas for this?
Thank you

Here is my code:-

```
FuelStoredInfo reportInfo =new FuelStoredInfo(context);
        reportInfo.open();
        fPrice=reportInfo.getReportData(this);
        fMileage = reportInfo.getReportMileage(this);
        fDates =reportInfo.getReportDates(this);
        reportInfo.close();


                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

                    TimeSeries fPriceseries = new TimeSeries("Fuel prices");
                    for (int i = 0; i < fDates.length; i++)
                    {
                            try 
                            {
                                fPriceseries.add(sdf.parse(fDates[i].trim()), fPrice[i]);
                            } 
                            catch (ParseException e)
                            {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }

                    TimeSeries fMileageSeries = new TimeSeries("Mileage");
                    for(int i=0;i<fDates.length;i++)
                    {
                        try 
                        {
                            fMileageSeries.add(sdf.parse(fDates[i].trim()), fMileage[i]);
                        } 
                        catch (ParseException e) 
                        {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }

dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
                        dataset.addSeries(fPriceseries);
                        dataset.addSeries(fMileageSeries);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the AChartEngine point of view, you can tweak the displaying period of time by changing the visible area and repainting the graph:

```
renderer.setXAxisMin(minDate);
renderer.setXAxisMax(maxDate);
chartView.repaint();
```