# How to display specific dates period on axis with TimeChartView using achartengine

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

I'm displaying set of dates by x-axis and scores by y-axis. But now dates displaying like this skipping whole weeks from 11 to 27 and then 12. But should be `11-18-25-1` - every week.

[image]

I saw similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299380/displaying-time-chart-in-achartengine-based-on-months-and-years). But not really get how to implement it. Now I'm doing this chart like this:

```
private String[] xValues = null;
  private double[] yValues = null;
  /** The main dataset that includes all the series that go into a chart. */
  private XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
  /** The main renderer that includes all the renderers customizing a chart. */
  private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
  /** The most recently added series. */
  private XYSeries mCurrentSeries;
  /** The most recently created renderer, customizing the current series. */
  private XYSeriesRenderer mCurrentRenderer;
  private GraphicalView mChartView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ....
    // set some properties on the main renderer
    mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bkg_green));
    mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(25);
    mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(25);
    mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(20);
    mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(25);
    mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
    mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] {50, 50, 25, 25 });
    mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01));
    mRenderer.setAxesColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    mRenderer.setLabelsColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    mRenderer.setXLabelsColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    mRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true,false);
    mRenderer.setPointSize(5);
    mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);
  }

//init chart with data
@Override public void onSuccess(final GraphResponse response) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        response.clearFromNullPoints();

        xValues = new String[response.getData().size()];
        yValues = new double[response.getData().size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < response.getData().size(); i++) {
            xValues[i] = response.getData().get(i).getDate();
            yValues[i] = response.getData().get(i).getValue();
        }

        if (mChartView == null) {
          LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
          mChartView = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(getApplicationContext(), mDataset, mRenderer,
              "dd.MM.yyyy");
          layout.addView(mChartView,
              new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                  LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
          addSeries();
        } else {
          mChartView.repaint();
        }
      }
    });
  }

 void addSeries() {
    TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Progress");
    // populate data
    for (int i = 0; i < xValues.length; i++) {
      try {
        series.add(dateFormat.parse(xValues[i]), yValues[i]);
      } catch (ParseException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }
    mDataset.addSeries(series);
    mCurrentSeries = series;
    // create a new renderer for the new series
    XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
    // set some renderer properties
    renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    renderer.setFillPoints(true);
    renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    renderer.setDisplayChartValuesDistance(40);
    renderer.setChartValuesTextSize(30);
    renderer.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    renderer.setLineWidth(3.0f);
    mCurrentRenderer = renderer;

    mChartView.repaint();
  }
```

How to display dates by x-axis with specific period - one week?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up setting own xAxis displaying period:

```
mRenderer.setXAxisMin(series.getX(0));
mRenderer.setXAxisMax(series.getX(0) + ONE_MONTH);
```

And setting up grid with 4 labels:

```
mRenderer.setXLabels(4);
```

Which give period 8 days and nice one month displaying on full width of display.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to have the chart display the actual data labels rather than the rounded ones. So, I suggest you do:

```
mRenderer.setXRoundedLabels(false);
```

Update: Another way to set your own labels is to disable the regular labels and add your custom ones:

```
mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
// one such call for every label
mRenderer.addXTextLabel(x, label);
```

Comment: This way I getting all labels by x-axis and grid which match x-values(10.07.2014,12.07.2014,14.07.2014) and they just mess. But I looking for a way to put labels on x-axis and points in period one week.(10.07.2014,17.07.2014,24.07.2014). Maybe there is other way to achieve this?

Comment: sorry was absent. Yes this is works, but now grid by x-axis not showing I can see only my specified labels without grid. Also grid by y-axis is showing and `mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);`.